# Confusion about Retrieve image from database

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am trying to retrieve images to gridview. But My images not displaying .I can get all the data except images. I keep the their paths in the database and I have a folder named Resimler stores images .I have been trying to figure out  three hours and i dont understand what is missing or wrong  This is my code

```
             <div>
    <asp:GridView ID="GvSehirBilgileri" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataSourceID="sql" 
        onrowdatabound="GvSehirBilgileri_RowDataBound" 
        Height="327px" Width="376px">
            <Columns>

                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        CityName :<asp:Label ID="lblSehirAdi" runat="server" 
                        Text='<%# Bind("CityName") %>'></asp:Label>
                        <br />
                        TaksiPrice :<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" 
                        Text='<%# Bind("TaxiPrice") %>'></asp:Label>
                        <br />
                        Resim :
                        <asp:Image ID="imgpath" runat="server" 
                        ImageUrl='<%#Bind("Path") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sql" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SQL %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [locCities]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server"
     onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you show an example value for Path column?

Comment: Sure. Resimler/10_Melbourne.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set ImageUrl like this:

```
ImageUrl='<%# string.Format("~/{0}", Eval("Path")) %>'
```